# ItemTouchHelper.Callback.getDefaultUIUtil().onDraw() change z-index

Tags: android

I use this method  ItemTouchHelper.Callback.getDefaultUIUtil().onDraw()  to implement swipe to options
all thing works fine but when the foreground is swiped the background appears but the clicks does not consume

```
override fun onChildDraw(
        c: Canvas, recyclerView: RecyclerView,
        viewHolder: RecyclerView.ViewHolder, dX: Float, dY: Float,
        actionState: Int, isCurrentlyActive: Boolean
    ) {

        if (viewHolder is PaymentCardsAdapter.ViewHolder) {

            val foregroundView: View = viewHolder.binding.viewForeground
            ItemTouchHelper.Callback.getDefaultUIUtil().onDraw(
                c, recyclerView, foregroundView, dX / 2, dY,
                actionState, isCurrentlyActive
            )

        }

    }
```

I tried to make foreground view here invisible, background now take the clicks, but any solutions

```
 override fun onSwiped(viewHolder: RecyclerView.ViewHolder, direction: Int) {
```